# Write and Read to multiple Textboxes from one TXT-file. C#

Tags: c#, save

I'm making a program that can save data from one combobox and two textboxes. When open the program, the saved data (in textfile) should open automaticly in Combobox with the text that was saved as a textfile. Also there should be one open-button that can open another textfile (if someone did a backup), and a delete button that can delete the selected "data" that is selected in the combobox.

With other words, if I save "Combobox: test 1", "Textbox1: test 2", "Textbox: test 3", and then save another data "Combobox: test a", "Textbox1: test b", "Textbox: test c".
When restarting the program, Combobox should have "test 1" and "test a" that can be choosed from.

The only feature I can get to work is saving the txt-file, but only open all text on the same row (witch I do not want). If this is impossible with the txt-file, It also works if someone can show me how to do this with a XML-file instead.

```
using System.IO;

namespace openclose
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string nl = "\r\n";
        TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter("test.txt");
        txt.Write((comboBox1.Text) + nl + (textBox1.Text) + nl + (textBox2.Text));
        txt.Close();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
        textBox2.Text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
        comboBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

I did also try to change the "savebutton" with this instead, it does save. But I can't figure out how to make the saved data show upp in the combobox so I can get back the data to textbox1 and textbox2.

```
        string path = @"Test.txt";

        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            // Create a file to write to.
            string createText = "";
            File.WriteAllText(path, createText, Encoding.UTF8);
        }

        string appendText = comboBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + textBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine;
        File.AppendAllText(path, appendText, Encoding.UTF8);

        string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);
        Console.WriteLine(readText);
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How I get it to work. right now the only code I got is that above. It only saves the data.

Comment: where exactly do you fail?

Comment: @Prasad. To get the text-file to add the latest data saved and get the textfile linked to the combobox so the saved data will show upp next time in the combobox.

Comment: And when saving once, it saves, but when saving again, it rewrite the textfile and delete the old saved data.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel, just updated the text for better explanation.